# Calculating Spark ML Heap Requirements

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning

I am trying to train a NaiveBayes model on my training sample of about 7 million observation. For each observation I have a SparseVector of about 27,000 features. I am using Spark 2.0 through an ipython notebook.

I am running it on a cluster with 4 workers, each one has one executor with 40 GB of RAM and 8 cores. The driver has 32 GB of RAM. Spark UI shows the dataset at 18.4 GB spread across 100 partitions.

The model fitting kicks in, but after a while I get the following OOM error.

I am trying to figure out a way to estimate RAM requirements to perform this fitting. Is there a solid way to calculate an estimate?

Also, I am allocating 40gb to each executor and can confirm it on the spark Master web UI page. However when I go into the application detail ui and click on Executors, it shows each one as having only 21.2 GB. Why does this happen?

Thanks in advance

Here is the dump:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o2392.fit.
: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofDouble.mkArray(ArrayBuilder.scala:518)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofDouble.resize(ArrayBuilder.scala:524)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofDouble.ensureSize(ArrayBuilder.scala:536)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofDouble.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuilder.scala:549)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuilder$ofDouble.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuilder.scala:511)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$$anonfun$flatten$2.apply(ArrayOps.scala:83)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$$anonfun$flatten$2.apply(ArrayOps.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$class.flatten(ArrayOps.scala:82)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatten(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayesModel.<init>(NaiveBayes.scala:56)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayes.run(NaiveBayes.scala:433)
    at org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayes$.train(NaiveBayes.scala:507)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.train(NaiveBayes.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.classification.NaiveBayes.train(NaiveBayes.scala:76)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.ml.Predictor.fit(Predictor.scala:71)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:237)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:280)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:128)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:211)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Yeah, spark can be greedy. Could you show how you start the application, what properties do you provide to sparkContext?

Comment: I am just setting the spark.driver.maxResultSize to 10g, the rest is default.

Comment: How much memory you have on that driver process? That's controlled by `spark.driver.memory` if you run it as spark-submit. Having maxResultSize won't help if you don't have enough memory to put that result.

Comment: The driver has 32GB. Box as a whole has 144.

Comment: You mean that when you start the driver process it has all of the 32 GB available?

Comment: I still believe you have to provide particular amount of memory for the driver process. For python I'd say that's the option `--driver-memory 16g`. For java / scala equivalent would be `-Dspark.driver.memory=16g`.

Comment: No, I specify it when I start ipython notebook. Pass that param to allocate the memory right off the bat. Either way, the fit operation runs on the executors.